# Imports not importing using Jest and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babeljs, enzyme

I am using Jest, Enzyme and Typescript, but for some reason certain imports are not working... they are undefined. For example, I have `import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';` in a file and when I run the tests, I get `Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined` for `ReactMarkdown`. Below are the configuration files

jest.config.js

```
/* tslint:disable */

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer"
  },
  testMatch: [
    "**/*.(test|spec).(ts|tsx)"
  ],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      babelConfig: true,
      tsConfig: "jest.tsconfig.json"
    }
  },
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "enzyme.js"
  ],
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: "<rootDir>/enzyme.js",
  coverageReporters: [
    "json",
    "lcov",
    "text",
    "text-summary"
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/mocks.js",
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/mocks.js"
  }
};
```

jest.ts.config.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "out",
    ".next"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it because you need `allowSyntheticDefaultImports:true` in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: No, I have that in my tsconfig

Comment: @mergesort did you find a solution for that problem?

Comment: Show your tsconfig. In my experience most if not all import issues stem from a bad tsconfig.

tsconfig allows you to define things like path aliases, and baseUrl that make for nicer paths, but dont really play well with other JS technolgies.

Comment: which version of react-markdown do you use?

Answer (score 1):

`createElement` is a method of the global `document` variable.  `document` is available to us in JavaScript when run within a browser, but not within `node`, thus the reason for `document` being undefined when something tries to run `document.createElement()` within a node unit test environment.

[JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) is a library that will create a fake `document` and `window` global variable that can be used for unit testing scenarios like the one you are trying to achieve.  Therefore, implementing JSDOM into your testing environment, especially the `ReactMarkdown` component which is throwing the error, could get you past this.

A lengthy description can be read at [Testing With Node, Jest, and JSDOM](https://freecontent.manning.com/testing-with-node-jest-and-jsdom/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `testEnvironment=node` is correct? because there is no `document` in Node and would explain the error message.

BTW `node` is the default value, so you could omit that option anyway

maybe try if this solves the problem:
`testEnvironment=jsdom`

and you might consider to use this library which will let you work immediately without do the whole setup on your own:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-enzyme

Answer (score 0):

Add a new node to the root object in jest.ts.config.json called "include" with the patters of your files, you will need to adapt this example to your code's naming conventions

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*test.tsx",
  "src/**/*test.ts"
]
```

This will include your jest files under this config and will prevent the "Cannot read" despicable error to show up.